Average of two pandas dataframes elements by elements results concatenated...why?
i have two dataframes:
print(d1.head())

         Codes       Prof Amp
477      0.7         3.0  0.724997
478      0.7         3.0  0.736914
479      0.7         3.0  0.612189
480      0.7         3.0  0.684321
481      0.7         3.0  0.950067

print(d1.shape)

(96, 3)

print(d2.head())

       Codes       Prof Amp
0      0.8         5.0  0.747135
1      0.8         5.0  1.370311
2      0.8         5.0  0.759630
3      0.8         5.0  1.125687
4      0.8         5.0  1.910926

print(d2.shape)

(96, 3)

when i use the following code:
dataM = d1.add(d2, fill_value=0)

        Code        Prof  Amp
0        0.8         5.0  0.747135
1        0.8         5.0  1.370311
2        0.8         5.0  0.759630
3        0.8         5.0  1.125687
4        0.8         5.0  1.910926

print(dataM.shape)

[192 rows x 3 columns]

but my target is
        Code        Prof  Amp
0        1.5         8.0  1.472132

......
and the shape should be the same [96 rows x 3 columns]
so how can i achieve that?
thank you in advance.

Reason is data alignment by index values - becuase different index values DataFrames are concatenated (and divided 2):
dataM = d1.add(d2, fill_value=0).div(2)
print (dataM)
     Codes  Prof       Amp
0     0.40   2.5  0.373567
1     0.40   2.5  0.685156
2     0.40   2.5  0.379815
3     0.40   2.5  0.562844
4     0.40   2.5  0.955463
477   0.35   1.5  0.362499
478   0.35   1.5  0.368457
479   0.35   1.5  0.306094
480   0.35   1.5  0.342160
481   0.35   1.5  0.475033

Need same index values in both DataFrames, so add DataFrame.reset_index with drop=True and for average divide by 2:
dataM = d1.reset_index(drop=True).add(d2.reset_index(drop=True), fill_value=0).div(2)
print (dataM)
   Codes  Prof       Amp
0   0.75   4.0  0.736066
1   0.75   4.0  1.053613
2   0.75   4.0  0.685909
3   0.75   4.0  0.905004
4   0.75   4.0  1.430496

Another idea is convert to numpy array and divide by 2:
dataM = d1.add(d2.to_numpy(), fill_value=0).div(2)


The operation fails, as your indexes are not aligned: the first DataFrame has indexes values starting at 477, while the second one starts at 0.
See pandas.add : Mismatched indices will be unioned together.
To align to indexes of the first DataFrame with the second, you can use d1.reset_index(drop=True).
dataM = d1.reset_index(drop=True).add(d2, fill_value=0)
print(dataM.shape)
# >>> (96, 3)


Your dataframes are not aligned, you should convert d2 to numpy with to_numpy:
out = d1.add(d2.to_numpy(), fill_value=0).div(2)

Output:
     Codes  Prof       Amp
477   0.75   4.0  0.736066
478   0.75   4.0  1.053613
479   0.75   4.0  0.685909
480   0.75   4.0  0.905004
481   0.75   4.0  1.430496

